# Check for variable (int that updates) in a list that grows

Tags: python, list, variables

I've got a long list of items that is updating information on a server using the 'requests' package.
To make my code run faster, I want to try to reduce to 'requestst.put()' by doing it only after a certain amount is reached, let's say 20 in the example code below.
Using watchdog observer it checks for incoming files, based on a certain string in the name of the file and then has to process it per option. Where for each of the certain string I += 1 the amount and then in each option also the total --> both numbers have to be taken in the requests (process code part).

I tried to do this the following way:

```
...
if "_4_" in text_file:
    Sec_totaal += 1
    alles_totaal += 1
    lijstje_Sec = list(range(0,Sec_totaal,20)
    if Sec_totaal in lijstje_Sec:
        #process code
if "_5_" in text_file:
    Fac_totaal += 1
    alles_totaal += 1
    lijstje_Fac = list(range(0,Fac_totaal,20)
    if Fac_totaal in lijstje_Fac:
        #process code
...
```

For some reason the process code doesn't even run the 'if' part (checked it first with a 'print()'), while the list is growing as expected and the output of totaal of each option should does match something in the list when printed. Or is checking a variable in a list not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range` is right-exclusive, that is `range(a, b)` creates a range `[a, b[`.

So you can never find `b` in `range(a, b)`, that's literally not possible.

That aside, you don't need to reify range to a list, it behaves pretty much like a list except free. Also skipping around is usually done using `%` e.g. to do something every 20, you do it if `i % 20 == 0`.

Comment: Maybe another followup question, can you use a variable as the modulo operator?